# ViewResolvers with excel views

Tags: excel, spring

I have two ordinary jsp pages in my Spring 3 application, and one is Excel view. The Excel wiev does not open Microsoft Excel sheet at all even thougt it should. I think it's a Resolver issue now.

I made views.properties:

xl.(class)=fi.utu.seurantaraporttisuodatin.service.Raportti
index.class=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
index.url=/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
success.class=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
success.url=/WEB-INF/jsp/success.jsp

defined it:

and got the error:

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'index': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'index': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:901)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.initFactory(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:251)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.loadView(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:194)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:158)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:77)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:372)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:52)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:948)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:901)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.initFactory(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:251)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.loadView(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:194)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:158)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:77)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 logs.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

I'm not sure if I'm solving my problem right at all. I could really use some help!

Comment: I'm also having the same issue with spring 3.0.7 and JBoss EAP 5.1. Please update if you found a solution.

Comment: Got it you should use index.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView instead of index.class=...

Answer (score 0):

you should use index.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView instead of index.class=...

Comment: things have been changed from spring 2.x to 3.x